# Python moving log files that have finished writing

Tags: python, python-3.x

My job log file modified times are set as a job starts. So if the job takes 20 minutes, the log file will be writing for those 20 minutes.

I need a script that says 'once the file is closed for writing (i.e. no more changes will be made), move it to another directory.

Is there a way to do this in Python? I can move files easy enough but how do I know the file is closed for writing?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

The with statement will automatically close the file before moving on.

```py
from shutil import move

with open('log.json') as myFile:
    .. do things

move('log.json', another_location)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I redirect the stdout of my job to stdout.log, which isn't handled in Python. So the file is produced outside of a Python process